# How to debug macruby?

Tags: malloc, macruby

I've encountered an inconsistent bug with MacRuby and have no idea how to go about debugging this. If anyone could help would be great.

I don't know if this is due to my own code or is it a bug in the MacRuby framework. I have a feeling it's my own code, something about over-retaining a piece of memory and hence the garbage collection failed.

This is the error from Xcode. Thanks.

```
CSV Wizard(30245,0x7fff704f7ca0) malloc: resurrection error for object 0x20199da20 while assigning {conservative-block}[196608](0x302360060)[117616] = Array[64](0x20199da20)
garbage pointer stored into reachable memory, break on auto_zone_resurrection_error to debug
CSV Wizard(30245,0x103781000) malloc: garbage block 0x20199da20(Array[64]) was over-retained during finalization, refcount = 1
This could be an unbalanced CFRetain(), or CFRetain() balanced with -release.
Break on auto_zone_resurrection_error() to debug.
CSV Wizard(30245,0x103781000) malloc: fatal resurrection error for garbage block 0x20199da20(Array[64]): over-retained during finalization, refcount = 1
```

Comment: What is the code that is causing this error?